# Remove from the beginning of DataFrame, all rows with at least one nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following dataframe:

```
     a    b     c
0  NaN  5.0   NaN
1  2.0  6.0   NaN
2  3.0  7.0  11.0
3  4.0  NaN  12.0
```

I want to remove all rows with at least one `NaN` from the first row until a 'full' row is found. For the example above, rows 0 & 1 contain `NaN` so they are dropped. Row 2 is a 'full' row so it is retained, along with all following rows.

i.e., I want to get:

```
     a    b     c
2  3.0  7.0  11.0
3  4.0  NaN  12.0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test non missing values per all rows by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.notna().all(axis=1).cummax()]

print (df)
     a    b     c
2  3.0  7.0  11.0
3  4.0  NaN  12.0
```